# GITLAB CI/CD: How to know if a pipeline is a tag pipeline, an MR pipeline or a scheduled pipeline?

Tags: testing, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

There's a part of the script which I want to run only if it's a tag pipeline. How do I represent that as a condition?

Comment: Pipelines are part of GitLab-ci, but not part of base Git. Whatever test you need is specific to GitLab Pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rules or the only keyword to run only on tags or merge requests.

rules:

```
job1:
  script:
    - echo "This job runs in merge request pipelines"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

only:

```
job1:
  script:
    - echo "This job runs in merge request pipelines"
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

To run only on tags you can use:

```
job1:
  script:
    - echo "This job runs only on tags"
  only:
    - tags
```

Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyrefs--exceptrefs